# Camera view warning - camera works fine

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

```
self.presentViewController(thePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The snapshot takes with no issues, but console shows this warning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depend on where do you call this method. try, to put it on a button click and check if the warning still there.

Comment: Thx. Tried it (a test button) to call takePicture() with same result. Calling it from an ActionSheet originally (ideally).

Comment: The warning still there?